# Display only the record which is in the top most stage in the SQL Server View

Tags: sql-server

I have a scenario where table has

Record_id, Record_Stage, Other_Column

```
1,MyFirstStage,Text1

1,MySecondStage,Text2

1,MyThirdStage,Text3

1,MyFourthStage,Text4

2,MyFirstStage,SText1

2,MySecondStage,SText2
```

My output should be based on record_id

1) The record with MyFourthStage for record_id 1

2) Record_id 2 with MySecondStage is displayed as there are no MyThirdStage and MyFourthStage

O/P

```
1,MyFourthStage,Text4

2,MySecondStage,SText2
```

> Note: The Record_Stage has just text in it and has some order
>   I am manipulating this case in a SQL Server view, It would be great help 
>   if someone can help me in this.

Comment: It's not clear to me how we're meant to know what the "top most stage" means. Are there only four possible stages, those shown? If not, how are even *we* meant to know it, let alone translate that requirement into SQL?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Answer: With a bufugly `CASE` expression and `ROW_NUMBER`.  And even then, the answer has some holes in it :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table has rather poor design, because you are trying to order records based on the semantic meaning of text, rather than on the text itself, or the lexicographic order of the text.  That being said, we may try ordering using a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT Record_id, Record_Stage, Other_Column
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Record_id
            ORDER BY CASE WHEN Record_Stage LIKE '%First%'  THEN 1
                          WHEN Record_Stage LIKE '%Second%' THEN 2
                          WHEN Record_Stage LIKE '%Third%'  THEN 3
                          WHEN Record_Stage LIKE '%Fourth%' THEN 4
                          ELSE 5 END DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

[image]

### Demo

This solution has many potential problems, first and foremost that to support more than 4 stages, we need to add more levels to the `CASE` expression.  A much better table design would be to add another column, probably a number, which maintains the order within each record group.

Answer (score -1):

Try this way

```
SELECT ID,stage,yourText 
FROM 
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER ( )   
    OVER ( PARTITION BY id order by id ) rownum,ID,stage,yourText  from @temp) as a
    where rownum = 1
```

Output

```
1   MyFirstStage    Text1
2   MyFirstStage    SText1
```

Fetch the last Record.

```
select a.id,b.stage,b.yourText  from
(select max(rownum) as rownum,a.id from 
(select ROW_NUMBER ( )   
OVER ( PARTITION BY id order by id ) rownum,ID,stage,yourText   from 
@temp)as a
group by  id) as a

left join

(select rownum,id,stage,yourText from 
(select ROW_NUMBER ( )   
OVER ( PARTITION BY id order by id ) rownum,ID,stage,yourText   from 
@temp)as a)b
on a.rownum = b.rownum and a.id = b.id
```

Output:

```
1   MyFourthStage   Text4
2   MySecondStage   SText2`
```

This is the Real Second Query:

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE(ID VARCHAR(10),    stage varchar(20),       yourText 
varchar(20))
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES

(1,'MyFirstStage','Text1'),

(1,'MySecondStage','Text2'),

(1,'MyThirdStage','Text3'),

(1,'MyFourthStage','Text4'),

(2,'MyFirstStage','SText1'),

(2,'MySecondStage','SText2')

select a.id,b.stage,b.yourText  from
(select max(rownum) as rownum,a.id from 
(select ROW_NUMBER ( )   
OVER ( PARTITION BY id order by id ) rownum,ID,stage,yourText   from 
@temp)as a
group by  id) as a

left join

(select rownum,id,stage,yourText from 
(select ROW_NUMBER ( )   
OVER ( PARTITION BY id order by id ) rownum,ID,stage,yourText   from 
@temp)as a)b
on a.rownum = b.rownum and a.id = b.id
```

Comment: No, `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY` containing the same expressions is almost always wrong. By *definition*, you know that all rows in a single partition share the *same* value for that expression. Therefore, the `ORDER BY` cannot be doing anything useful to distinguish *between* those rows.

Comment: Your output doesn't match what the OP is expecting.

Comment: my mistake.. i thought it he need the latest one.. thanks @Tim

Comment: And yet when I run your second query I can get output like `id   stage          yourText
---- -------------- ---------
1    MyThirdStage   Text3
2    MyFirstStage   SText1` - because as I've already told you, those `order by` clauses that you're giving aren't in any way useful.

Comment: try it @Damien.

Comment: @VijunavVastivch - I can. You're relying on coincidence. Can we agree that just adding a constraint to the table shouldn't change the query results? If so, try adding `primary key (stage,id)` at the end of your table variable declaration and re-run the query - on my machine, it then produces the results I gave in my previous comment. But even if it doesn't on yours, that's the whole point - your query *isn't* deterministic where it needs to be.

Comment: thanks for your comment and advice.. all i want to do is just to help then. We are in different machine and we don't even know the schema structure of that particular problem from above.

Comment: `PARTITION BY id` - okay, so we have one partition containing four rows, all with id 1. `ORDER BY id` - okay, but we know that all of these rows have an id of 1. That's the point - *any* of those rows can be assigned *any* of the row numbers. It's *wrong*.